# I'm getting an Error in C++ - error: cannot convert ‘cv::Point_<int>’ to ‘cv::Point* {aka cv::Point_<int>*}’ in return

Tags: c++, c, opencv, wrapper

I'm try to run the code below and I'm getting an error.  I'm creating an wrapper for an OpenCV function called 'Mat::at' and I'm trying to get it to compile to an '.so' on Ubuntu Trusty using 'G++'. I listed the contents of my '.cpp' file my '.hpp' file my error and my compile command below. I would appreciate any help on returning this C++ OpenCV function as a C pointer. Because that is my goal. Thank you.

**Error:**

```
 error: cannot convert ‘cv::Point_<int>’ to ‘cv::Point* 
    {aka cv::Point_<int>*}’ in return
 return self->at<Point>(row, col);
```

(I also get the normal "Contol reaches end of non-void function error")

**Cpp:**

```
 Point* cv_Mat_at_Point(Mat* self, int row, int col) {
   return self->at<Point>(row, col);
 }
```

**Hpp:**

```
 Point* cv_Mat_at_Point(Mat* self, int row, int col)
```

**Compile Command:**

```
 g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o c-binding.so c-binding.cpp
```

Edit for RedX:

```
Point* cv_create_Point(int x, int y) {
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Comment: `self->at()` returns a `Point` not a `Point*`

Comment: To be precise, according to documentation it returns a `Point&` ( http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at ).

Comment: @RedX I know it does but I have a lot of C wrappers for other funtions in OpenCV and they only accept Point*.  See latest edit for how I create a Point* to give to them....it works.  It must output Point*. I hava alot of other functions that output Point* successfully and the c++ function they wrap returns Point also as in my question edit.

Comment: @Medinoc can you show me how to make this work?

Comment: would return &self->at<Point>(row, col); work for you ?

Comment: @michaeltang Thanks that worked...You should post an answer so I  can vote you up=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be  `return &self->at<Point>(row, col);`

since the function is expecting Point*